# probability distribution over spike trains

Tags: probability

In one [paper](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/biorxiv/early/2019/01/17/517888/DC1/embed/media-1.pdf?download=true) eq. 11 introduces a probability distribution over all possible spike trains of an ouput neuron $Y_i$ given an input spike train $\mathbf X$:

$$
P_{\mathbf w_{i}}(Y_i|\mathbf X) \approx \Bigg [\prod_{t' \in Y_i} \phi(v_i^*(t')) \Bigg ] \exp \Bigg(-\int_0^T \phi \Big(v_i^*(t)\Big) dt \Bigg)
$$

where

$$
\Bigg [\prod_{t' \in Y_i} \phi(v_i^*(t')) \Bigg ]
$$
is the probability of having a spike at $t' \in Y_i$ and

$$
\exp \Bigg(-\int_0^T \phi \Big(v_i^*(t)\Big) dt \Bigg)
$$

is the probability of having no spikes elsewhere in the spike trains. The function $\phi(v_i^*(t'))$ (if I understand correctly) maps some activity $v_i^*(t')$ to the range [0, 1], i.e. it is a sigmoid.

Can somebody explain why the probability of having no spikes elsewhere in the spike train is $\exp \Bigg(-\int_0^T \phi \Big(v_i^*(t)\Big) dt \Bigg)$ and not $\Bigg [\prod_{t \in Y_i} \big(1 - \phi(v_i^*(t))\big) \Bigg ]$

Thanks!